# C++ char array compare ' ' and '\0' and counter doesn't work

Tags: c++, arrays, char

I'm new to C++. I have a simple practice function I try to count how many words in a full name, first I pass a char array fullName to nameCount function with a counter then it will compare each char in the array with ' 'and '\0' if it meet any of these 2 chars, counter will +1. But I don't know why the counter give back a very large number.
Please help me out with the code.
Thanks a lot.

```
#include <iostream>
    
using namespace std;
   
    
void nameCount (char[],int&);
    
const int LENGTH =30;
int main()
{
    char name[LENGTH];
    int count=0;
    cout<<"Input full name: ";
    cin.getline(name, LENGTH);
    nameCount(name, count);
    cout<<count;
    return 0;
}

void nameCount(char fullName[],int& count) {
    
    for(int i=0; i<LENGTH;i++){
        if (fullName[i]==' ' || fullName[i]=='\0')
            count++;
    } 
}
```

Example & Result:

1. Input Full Name:John Smith

0

Comment: I assume that you pass an uninitialized variable as the `count` parameter to the function.  Try this: `void nameCount(char fullName[],int& count) { count = 0; ...` or provide us with a [mre].

Comment: I'd suggest using a `std::string` rather than a`char` array.

Comment: I'm addition you probably need to pass `count` by reference if you want to access the updated value in the calling function

Comment: I uploaded full code and try the pass count by reference but it didn't update the count

Comment: Because you didn't _call_ the function?

Comment: Additionally `cin.getline(name, count);` should be `cin.getline(name, LENGTH);`. In your version `count` is zero so `getline` is not going to read anything.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You have the common newbie confusion between parameters and return values.

When you want a function to calculate something you **return** that value from the function, You don't pass the variable as a parameter.

Here's how your code should look

```
int nameCount(char fullName[]) {
    int count = 0;
    for (int i = 0; i < LENGTH; i++) {
        if (fullName[i] == ' ' || fullName[i] == '\0')
            count++;
    }
    return count;
}
```

and here's how you call the function

```
int count = nameCount("John Smith");
```

Even with that improvement there appear to be bugs in your code. I would suggest this as an improvement

```
int nameCount(char fullName[]) {
    int count = 0;
    for (int i = 0; fullName[i] != '\0'; i++) {
        if (fullName[i] == ' ')
            count++;
    }
    return count;
}
```

However since I can't see the rest of your code this might not be right.

**EDIT**

So full source code is now available (thanks).

Here's a fully working `main`

```
#include <iostream>
    
using namespace std;
   
    
int nameCount (char[]);
    
const int LENGTH =30;
int main()
{
    char name[LENGTH];
    cout<<"Input full name: ";
    cin.getline(name, LENGTH);
    cout << name_count(name) << '\n';
    return 0;
}
```

And as stated your function actually counts spaces not words, so `nameCount("John Smith")` returns one not two, but that's a different problem.

Comment: Wouldn't your improved code return 1 for `John Smith` instead of 2?

Comment: @AlanBirtles Yes I was leaving that algorithmic problem until the various other problems were sorted out. I've made a note of it now.

Comment: The original code did return the number of words though (assuming no consecutive spaces) by counting the trailing null terminator

Comment: I think set count =1 it will solve the problem

Comment: but if is there anyway we can count '\0' at the end also will be perfect! I also don't understand why when I set condition of for-loop i<LENGTH the count will return crazy large number?

Comment: @Tobi Because `LENGTH` is the size of the array in `main` it is not the length of your string (which will probably be smaller). You find the length of a string by checking for the nul terminator (or by using the `strlen` function which does this for you).

Comment: I see, thank you for the info, I'll check on it

Comment: Setting `count = 1` improves the code, but you still get wrong answer if there are consecutive spaces. Fundamentally the algorithm needs changing. Imagine if the input is `"John          Smith"`, that's two names but a lot more spaces.

Comment: @john I totally understand what you mean. but as I say before I'm newbie and this is an practice example I found in the book. Of course, in real program it will not work. The only problem I got right now is when I left blank, the count still 1. Is there any idea to improve that issue?

Comment: maybe like check if the array is empty then count=0 if not then count ' '. maybe?

Comment: @Tobi Seems reasonable. But you still need to deal with consecutive spaces.

Comment: @Tobi Here's what I would do, I would count letters (not spaces) that either occur after a space or are the first character in the string.

Comment: @Tobi So in "John Smith" I count the 'J' because its a letter and its the first character in the string, and I count the 'S' because its a letter and it follows a space. You can add as many extra spaces as you like and that will still work.

Comment: That is a great idea. Thx